# Making comparison in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Developed a function in Clojure to check if inputs for the :maxlength and :minlength is 1-3 characters long and the text in associated column is within the range of min and max. Is there a cleaner way to do this? I'd appreciate if a more efficient method is suggested especially the if form.

```
(defn range-text-length
 "input = {:col val :minlength minlength :maxlength maxlength}
  Expects 3 parameter key/value combinations:
   :col The column containing the text value
   :maxlength integer value greater than zero up to 3 characters long
 Catch any rows where the column contains text that is shorter than the Minimum Length or longer than the Maximum Length"
 [row input]
 (let [{:keys [col  minlength maxlength ]} input
    minlength-count (count (str minlength))
    maxlength-count (count (str maxlength))
    max (read-string (str maxlength))
    min (read-string (str minlength))]
  (if (and (and (> maxlength-count 0) (<= maxlength-count 3) (number? max) (> max 0))
      (and (> minlength-count 0)(<= minlength-count 3)(number? min)(> min 0)))
  (and (>= (count (get row col)) min) (<= (count (get row col)) max))
  (throw (Exception. "length must be a positive integer value with no more than 3 digits.")))))
```

And I call the function thus:

```
(catch-out-of-range-text-length ["weert" "sertt" "qwertyuiopasdfg" "asert"] {:col 2 :minlength 2 :maxlength 15})
```

Comment: Can you append a sample of the data? Also, as per the exception, are all the columns numeric?

Comment: It actually works, just asking for a cleaner way to make the comparison in the if form @Frank C.

Comment: Candidate to be moved to codereview

Comment: Suggest you remove the `core.logic` tag. It's not about the logic of ordinary Clojure. It's a logic programming sub-language similar to Prolog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: nested `and` is redundant. Since the code can't differentiate which part of the condition was false, there is no effect of nested calls to `and` as opposed to putting all the clauses in the same `and`.

Next, `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` all take a variable number of arguments, and with a bit of refactoring you can combine calls that share a term.

Finally, rather than testing if something is greater than 0, you can directly test if it is positive with `pos?`.

```
(defn range-text-length
 "input = {:col val :minlength minlength :maxlength maxlength}
  Expects 3 parameter key/value combinations:
   :col The column containing the text value
   :maxlength integer value greater than zero up to 3 characters long
 Catch any rows where the column contains text that is shorter than the Minimum Length or longer than the Maximum Length"
 [row input]
 (let [{:keys [col  minlength maxlength ]} input
       minlength-count (count (str minlength))
       maxlength-count (count (str maxlength))
       max (read-string (str maxlength))
       min (read-string (str minlength))]
   (if (and (> 4 maxlength-count 0)
            (number? max)
            (pos? max)
            (> 4 minlength-count 0)
            (number? min)
            (pos? min))
     (>= max (count (get row col)) min)
     (throw (Exception. "length must be a positive integer value with no more than 3 digits.")))))
```

Comment: Thanks @noisesmith.. I'm very new to Clojure, can you please point me to good resources on Clojure.

Comment: http://clojure.org actually has really good introductory documentation. Also http://conj.io is a good reference.

Comment: @noisesmith: Are you available for mentorship.. I'd want to learn from you..I'm sure we can work out something..Kindly send me your contact email, thanks

Comment: @OlajideMichaelAderibigbe I'm flattered but I have full time work already.

Comment: @noisesmith I have a challenge with a clojure code I wrote and wondering if you could point me in the right direction, I'm not getting the correct output

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is equivalent to yours:

```
(defn range-text-length [row input]
  (let [in-range? (fn [n] (< 0 n 1000))
        {:keys [col  minlength maxlength ]} input
        ]
    (if (every? in-range? [minlength maxlength])
      (<= minlength (count (row col)) maxlength)
      (throw (Exception. "length must be a positive integer with no more than 3 digits.")))))
```

Comment: Nice alternate approach!

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already marked @noisesmith as answer. Whilst that was going on I was toying around and produced the following:

```
(defn range-text-length
  [row {:keys [col minlength maxlength] :as input}]
  (if-let [x (and (and (pos? minlength) (< minlength 1000))
                  (and (pos? maxlength) (< maxlength 1000))
                  (and (>= (count (get row col)) minlength)
                       (<= (count (get row col)) maxlength)))]
    true
    (throw (Exception. "length must be a positive integer value with no more than 3 digits."))))
```

Despite the variadic capability of `and` I separated for readability.

**EDIT:** Did away with the `if-let`:

```
(defn range-text-length
  [row {:keys [col minlength maxlength] :as input}]
  (or (and (and (pos? minlength) (< minlength 1000))
           (and (pos? maxlength) (< maxlength 1000))
           (and (>= (count (get row col)) minlength)
                (<= (count (get row col)) maxlength)))
    (throw (Exception. "length must be a positive integer value with no more than 3 digits."))))
```

Answer (score -1):

`if` clause tidied up and preconditions used to avoid polluting the real purpose of the function with the assumed preconditions. Some extra [examples](https://ianrumford.github.io/blog/2012/11/17/first-take-on-contracts-in-clojure/)

```
(defn range-text-length
  "input = {:col val :minlength minlength :maxlength maxlength}
  Expects 3 parameter key/value combinations:
  :col The column containing the text value
  :maxlength integer value greater than zero up to 3 characters long
  Catch any rows where the column contains text that is shorter than the Minimum Length or longer than the Maximum Length"
  [row input]
  {: pre [(let [{:keys [col  minlength maxlength ]} input
                     minlength-count (count (str minlength))
                     maxlength-count (count (str maxlength))
                     max (read-string (str maxlength))
                     min (read-string (str minlength))
                     crc (count (get row col))]
                 (not (and (pos? maxlength-count)
                      (pos? minlength-count)
                      (pos? max)
                      (pos? min)
                      (<= maxlength-count 3) 
                      (<= minlength-count 3)
                      (>= crc min) 
                      (<= crc max))))]}
  (do (println "do my stuff with satisfied preconditions")))
```

Comment: Preconditions are not for exceptional runtime conditions, they are for catching errors in program logic. They can be turned off via a flag to the jvm, and this program would be incorrect if assertions were turned off. Also, this answer does not duplicate the logic of the original (working) code.

Comment: That's true but arguable. A user who never heard about pre-conditions will rarely know he can disable them by a JVM flag. I answered for the intended audience trying to introduce a new concept not for experts. And the flag is something you should set __indeed__ so in 99% of cases it won't be a problem.

Comment: You can change your vote @OlajideMichaelAderibigbe afaik

Comment: @JamesSharp Thanks for helping out, my unit test failed though..  :(